# ANDROID STUDIO BUILD ERROR org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

Tags: android, gradle

I am facing this kind of error on my android studio 3.2
The following is my `logcat`

```
org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:786: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/navigationMode' with config ''.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:786: error: resource previously defined here.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:795: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/displayOptions' with config ''.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:795: error: resource previously defined here.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:958: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_scrollFlags' with config ''.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:958: error: resource previously defined here.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1014: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/tickMarkTintMode' with config ''.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1014: error: resource previously defined here.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1169: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/actionBarSize' with config ''.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1169: error: resource previously defined here.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1478: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/behavior_peekHeight' with config ''.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1478: error: resource previously defined here.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1517: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/collapsedTitleGravity' with config ''.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1517: error: resource previously defined here.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1538: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/expandedTitleGravity' with config ''.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1538: error: resource previously defined here.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1560: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_collapseMode' with config ''.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1560: error: resource previously defined here.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1581: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/buttonTintMode' with config ''.
D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1581: error: resource previously defined here.
Command: C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\a30cb4bf0ed73f1c105add4760ddc4a7\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        D:\Ticketing\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: It occurs when your resource file not successfully loaded due to image name or duplicate strings file or in style.xml error. please check all the resource file and do consider that image file do not have any number or special character and also it should be in lowwercase

Answer (score 0):

As your log said,it's your resource conflict issue,you can search conflicted resource name by shortcut Crtl+shift+F,you will find two or more resource and delele some,it will address your problem.